# Form.cs not being updated by changes to Form.cs[Design]

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and I am just messing around with the controls to see how things work.  I made one form that had a single button that, when pushed, simply printed "Hello World" to the screen.  To try something more complicated I deleted that button and added various other tools to the Form.  However the code in the Form.cs file was not updated to reflect these changes to the design and I can find no way to update it manually.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Check Designer file of that form.

Comment: What changes in Form.cs are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Button` had an `OnClick` event, it will NOT be erased when the `Button` is erased. Visual Studio assumes that this code may be used somewhere else and is not data-destructive.

Every time you delete a control that you had events, they will remain. You must manually go through and clean up your code.

EDIT:

To make the "new code" appear for the newer controls, you must either double click the button to generate the default event for that control, or go into the Properties of that control and generate the code for the events there.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Form1.Designer.cs (assuming your form is called Form1) you will see a list of all the code that was generated by building your app, within there you will see your button name, if the button is deleted you should be able to safely delete the code between the comments.

Comment: just want to point out that NORMALLY we try to stay out of the design.cs file as it is autogenerated. Yes manual edits can work, just saying typically one edits via the designer view, and puts code in the plain .cs file.

Comment: I think he means the code (Form.cs) file was not updated. This is common in VS when reconfiguring the designer.

Comment: @Mike Webb: I do mean that the code file was not updated.  The code for the button I deleted was not removed and the code for the new controls I added was not added.  As I said, I can find no way to force this to happen.

Comment: @Kevin: Code like click events and things, in my experience, will not usually get deleted. You may have to delete them from Form.cs manually. What was code you expected to be added that was not added?

Comment: @Mike: I deleted one button then I added a couple of text boxes, a new button, and a label.  The code in Form1.cs didn't reflect any of these changes.

Comment: @Kevin: See my response below.

Comment: @Kevin: I updated my response. Let me know there if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the changes in **Form1.Designer.cs** file 
the code is below these lines....

```
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
```

To update manually just call manual_update().

```
manual_update()
{

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "new button";
        b.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        b.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

You can do almost everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Also Try rebuilding.. if you removed it from the form sometimes VS does not remove that code from the designer.. and you will have to manually remove it / update it.. also make sure you don't have any compile errors as well

if you have errors .. they changes may not be shown until the error(s) have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you added other tools in the front-end Form file, make sure that your webcontrols in the Form are connected to whatever event handlers you have.

Also, make sure you're re-compiling/re-building your page, just for sanity check and if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Form1.Designer.cs` file, the designer code lies in this file. If u cant see the file in solution explorer than there is a button on the solution explorer pane on top, that is `view files`. Click it.

Visual studio provides you drag and drop functionality of controls, and to change the properties just right click on the control and click 'properties'. So actually you may not need to change the designer code. But you can as u like...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then the code that adds controls and changes control properties is all auto-generated and resides, for your example, in Form1.Designer.cs. **This file should generally never be touched except by Visual Studio.**

If you want to add controls manually you should do it in the Form1.cs after the `InitializeComponent()` call or in an event like the `Form_Load` event. Here is an example of adding a button in a form load event:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Left = 10;
    b.Top = 10;
    b.Text = "Button!";
    this.Controls.Add(b); //'this' would be the form self-pointer
}
```

Events are different. These are what will change in Form1.cs, but changes made to the designer will not always be reflected in the code-behind file for events. This is the nature of VS. Sometimes deleting a button will not delete the events from the code and vise-versa.

You may have to remove events from controls manually in the code file.

Code for added controls can usually be forced by changing the control in the designer, but at least one thing that won't change is event names when the control name changes. For instance, if a button is called `button1` and links to the click event `button1_click(object sender, EventAgrs e)`, changing the button name to `button12345` will not change the event name.

You can change linked events in the designer by opening the control properties and clicking on the lightning bolt. This shows all events for a control. Double clicking in an event field will either take you to the linked event or generate an event if the field is blank. This dialog will also allow multiple controls to link to a single event.

Here is an example of the event properties dialog:
[image: Events dialog]

You may just have to fiddle with adding controls, linking events, removing controls, etc. to get a feel for when changes are updated across both designer and code-behind and when changes are not updated.